# Visual Studio can't show folder of C++ files

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have used Visual Studio 2017 to open a vs2010 MFC project.
It could be opened well in the first time.
However, afterwards, it reminds me to do some update. After that, the file cannot be load in the resource view.

[image: Screenshot]

How to reconfigure Visual Studio 2017 to show the resource view?

Answer (score 0):

To open the resource view window Click `Resource View` on the `View` menu or Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>. But if you mean why the load failed it may be a data crash depending on the situation.